# multiprocessing.Process is blocking the return statement when running with uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, connexion

I am running an API back and currently, I am using a `subprocess.Popen`. As the called modules are pure python my idea is to run it with `multiprocessing.Process` or `Pull`. The request is processed like this:

1. A request arrives at a `Connexion` endpoint
2. Some preprocessing is done
3. The function is opened with Popen
4. The request returns a 200 without waiting for 3. to finish

When replacing:

```
Popen(...)
```

with

```
p = Process(target=...)
p.start()
```

this happens to multiprocessing **with** uwsgi:

1. A request arrives at a `Connexion` endpoint
2. Some preprocessing is done
3. The function is opened with Process
4. The request returns a 200 immediately, but a second request to the same endpoint will require the previous 3 to finish.

in if I run it on https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker:

...

4. The request waits until 3 is finished and then returns a 200

It works as espected if I run the process with `python -m ...`.

My uwsgi.ini looks like this

```
 [uwsgi]
 module = myapp
 callable = app
 lazy-apps = true
 stats-http = true
 http = 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: add the following line to your uwsgi.ini  `enable-threads = true`

Answer (score 0):

Your uwsgi.ini should enable threads, which are by default, blocked.

Change it to the following

```
[uwsgi]
module = myapp
callable = app
lazy-apps = true
stats-http = true
http = 127.0.0.1:8080
enable-threads = true
```